# How can I build criteria around a percentage?

Tags: administration, criteria, approval-process

**Conditions suedo code would be:**

IF Total Adjustment Percentage IS  Greater Than 5%

**I’ve tried the following to no avail.**

```
Total_Adjustment_Percentage__c  >  -5  (the true value in database show as negative value)
Total_Adjustment_Percentage__c  >  5
Total_Adjustment_Percentage__c  >  .05 (doesn’t allow the period)
```

thanks.

Comment: Are you sure this is a percent field? I just tried a new View filtering on Opportunity.Probability (Percent (3,0)) and Salesforce automatically converted .05 to 0.05 without issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try Total_Adjustment_Percentage__c  > -0.05

Comment: Keep Asking and answering touting the forum so that more people are helped.